# React JS - Method for handling loading state of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I have the following code which loads some posts, and whilst loading, displays a loading indicator. Once posts have been fetched, the actual posts are mapped and displayed on screen, and `isLoading` is set to false

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   const posts = await axios.get('/posts')
   setPosts(posts)
   setIsLoading(false)
}, [])

return (
   isLoading ? <Spinner />
   :  
    <div>
       Here we map the posts - Loop over and display posts
    </div>
         
)
```

Instead of the code above, why couldn't I remove the `isLoading` variable, and state that if the posts array is **null** or **empty**, display a loading indicator, **else** display and map over the posts array

This would look like this:
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

```
useEffect(() => {
   const posts = await axios.get('/posts')
   setPosts(posts)
}, [])

return (
   posts.length === 0 || posts === null ? <Spinner loading=true /> 
     :
   <div>
     // Display and map over posts
   </div>
)
```

This would mean you could remove the loading variable in **state**. Are there any potential problems using this solution, and if so, what are they?

Comment: `Are there any potential problems using this solution` -- what if there really ARE no posts? What if you do `get POSTS` and the actual fact of the matter is, it's an empty array because there's none?

Comment: @TKoL Ok, so this is one reason to use a `isLoading` state variable. Are there also any more potential problems with my original solution?

Comment: none come to mind - the lesson of my comment is, we have to make sure we're showing the 'loading' icon based on conditions that REALLY ARE about whether the data is loading, and not making assumptions about data, like 'it must be loading because the data array is empty'. Fewer assumptions is better, render the things you want to render based on variables that actual determine if you want to render them.

Comment: Potential issue here is also if for some reason your api call fails, having the loading state you could show the user the difference between a failed request and a loading request, best thing for UX.

Comment: @DevonRay Could you elaborate on what you mean by this, as I don't quite understand this

Comment: @samalvis if you use the empty array state to show hide the loading you have no way of knowing if the api failed, empty or simply still loading and you cant feed that back to the user, they would end up waiting for a response. If something goes wrong better not to waste a users time

Answer (score 0):

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/posts');
      setPosts(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message || 'An error occurred');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);

return (
  <>
    {isLoading && <Spinner loading={true} />}
    {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
    {!isLoading && !error && posts.length === 0 && <Spinner loading={true} />}
    {!isLoading && !error && posts.length > 0 && (
      <div>
        {/* Display and map over posts */}
      </div>
    )}
  </>
);
```